# opengl_error_break

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm developing a game for iPhone and is pretty far along, but one thing bugs me when using Instrument a see that something called opengl_error_break is taking LOTS of valueable time.  The caller seems to be MBXGLEngine which is a part of the OpenGLES framework but I have no idea of what it does or how to debug it.

Does any one here have a clue about this? Here's a [screen dump](http://img213.imageshack.us/i/instruments.tif/) that can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on OS 3.0?

I saw the same behaviour when briefly testing on an old iPhone with OS 3.0.

I didn't come up with an explanation, although I suspected that perhaps
the GL ES implementation was spewing errors at me. It wasn't.

I was trying to optimize my framerate so in the end I ignored this
and just concentrated on lowering the "renderer utilization".
Now I'm hitting my framerate and all's well that end's well.

Still curious about `opengl_error_break`. I never see it on my iPodTouch/2.x.

Comment: You're right in that it's targeted for OS 3.0. But it's actually not required. I'll try with 2.x and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

It's a red herring. The time is actually spent in other OpenGL functions, but Instruments is confused.

In some OS/SDK versions, all OpenGL symbols are hidden except for `opengl_error_break` (which allows you to continue to set a breakpoint on it). This confuses Instruments (and Shark). Basically, Instruments knows the execution is in an OpenGL library, but since the only symbol it can find is `opengl_error_break`, it guesses (incorrectly) that `opengl_error_break` is executing.

This is [explained by an Apple developer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/54824#54824) on the Apple Developer forums. [A later reply goes into more detail.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/87726#87726)

Comment: I think this also was mentioned in a WWDC 2009 video on performance tuning using Shark, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but [this page](http://memfrag.se/ShadesOfNinja/wiki/Debugging.html) suggests it's a symbol useful for getting a breakpoint on an OpenGL ES error. This of course contradicts posts like [this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=539786) that claim their code runs without reporting any errors from OpenGL ES, yet spends time in that function. Weird.

Comment: I've read those to, but as you said they doent give much of an answer.